# Mandar datos de una consulta por email con formato html

Tags: php

alguien me podria ayudar a meter mis datos de la consulta en una tabla, el email me lo envia pero no me muestra los datos almacenados.

```
 <?php
    $conect = new mysqli("localhost", "onethost_horacio", "MPADT-2018", "onethost_MPA");
    /*$v3=$_POST['codigo'];*/
    //$sql = "SELECT * from InformacionGeneral WHERE Delegacion like '%$v3%'";
    $sql = "SELECT * from InformacionGeneral";
    $resultado=mysqli_query($conect,$sql);
    while($fila=mysqli_fetch_assoc ($resultado)){
    ?>   
        <tr>
        <td><?php $idgeneral=$fila["Id_General"]?>
        <td><?php $delegacion=$fila["Delegacion"]?>
        <td><?php $parroquia=$fila["Parroquia"]?>
        <td><?php $tios=$fila["Tios_Rensponsables"]?>
        <td><?php $asesor=$fila["Asessor_Espiritual"]?>
        <td><?php $fecha=$fila["Fecha"]?>
        <td><?php $tiosresponsables=$fila["Tios_apoyo"]?>
         </tr>
    <?php
    $mensaje1 = "<html>
        <head><title>Email con HTML</title></head>
        <body><h1>Email con HTML</h1>
        Esto es un email que se envía en el formato HTML
        <hr>
        Enviado por mi programa en PHP
        <hr>
        <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Id General</th><th>Delegacion</th><th>Parroquia</th><th>Tios</th><th>Asesor</th><th>Fecha</th><th>Tios Responsables</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $idgeneral.;?></td><td><?php echo $delegacion.;?></td><td><?php echo $parroquia.;?></td><td><?php echo $tios.;?></td><td><?php echo $asesor.;?></td><td><?php echo $fecha.;?></td><td><?php echo $tiosresonsables.;?></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </body>
        </html>";

    ////////////////////////////
    $asunto = "Datos de usuario";
    ///////////////////////////
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    //////////////////////////////////
    $headers .= "From: Jose Luis Santiago < jose@gmail.com >\r\n";
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    $para='santiago09617@gmail.com';
    /////////////////////////////////

    }
    $bool = mail($para,$asunto,$mensaje1,$headers);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema radica en la forma como estas generando el `html` debido a que no puedes incluir dentro de una variable las etiquetas `PHP`, para que te funcione de manera correcta, tendrias que implementar tu código de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
    $conect = new mysqli("localhost", "onethost_horacio", "MPADT-2018", "onethost_MPA");
    /*$v3=$_POST['codigo'];*/
    //$sql = "SELECT * from InformacionGeneral WHERE Delegacion like '%$v3%'";
    $sql = "SELECT * from InformacionGeneral";
    $resultado=mysqli_query($conect,$sql);
    $contenido = '';
    while($fila=mysqli_fetch_assoc ($resultado))
    {
        $idgeneral         = $fila["Id_General"];
        $delegacion        = $fila["Delegacion"];
        $parroquia         = $fila["Parroquia"];
        $tios              = $fila["Tios_Rensponsables"];
        $asesor            = $fila["Asessor_Espiritual"];
        $fecha             = $fila["Fecha"];
        $tiosresponsables  = $fila["Tios_apoyo"];

        $contenido .= '
         <tr>
           <td> '.$idgeneral.' </td>
           <td> '.$delegacion.'  </td>
           <td> '.$parroquia.'  </td>
           <td> '.$tios.'  </td>
           <td> '.$asesor.'  </td>
           <td> '.$fecha.'  </td>
           <td> '.$tiosresponsables.' </td>
         </tr>';

    }

    $mensaje1 = "
      <html>
        <head><title>Email con HTML</title></head>
        <body><h1>Email con HTML</h1>
        Esto es un email que se envía en el formato HTML
        <hr>
        Enviado por mi programa en PHP
        <hr>
        <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Id General</th><th>Delegacion</th><th>Parroquia</th><th>Tios</th><th>Asesor</th><th>Fecha</th><th>Tios Responsables</th>
        </tr>
        ".$contenido."
        </table>
        </body>
        </html>";
    ////////////////////////////
    $asunto = "Datos de usuario";
    ///////////////////////////
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    //////////////////////////////////
    $headers .= "From: Jose Luis Santiago < jose@gmail.com >\r\n";
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    $para='santiago09617@gmail.com';
    /////////////////////////////////

    $bool = mail($para,$asunto,$mensaje1,$headers);
    ?>
```

Espero mi respuesta haya sido de utilidad, si fue así no olvides dejar tu calificación positiva.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo pruebo y te dijo.

Comment: Muchas gracias! quedo perfecto, disculpa tengo algo en mente pero no se si se pueda que cuando se haga la consulta y se envíe en  formato de excel por email?

Comment: No comprendo muy bien a que te refieres cuando dices format excel, si me puedes explicar de manera mas detallada depronto te pueda ayudar

Comment: mira quiero que el usuario vea la informacion de la tabla y cuando le de enviar a x destinatario que lo reciba en formato de excel, que todos los datos esten alojados en un archivo excel. no se si me explique bien

Comment: Vale @JoseLuisSantiagoPacheco ya te comprendí, tu quieres que se envié un excel adjunto en el email, para eso, debes crear primero el excel en tu servidor, luego enviarlo adjunto en el email y por ultimo, eliminarlo del servidor para que no te ocupe espacio de manera innecesaria. Te recomiendo ver este articulo que te puede servir de guia: https://medium.com/matrix-developments/php-excel-una-ligera-alternatva-para-phpexcel-f18623356c91

Comment: entonces tengo que almacenar mis datos obtenidos por mi consulta y almacenarlos en un archivo excel  para que cuando le de enviar por correo, el usuario reciba los datos en en un archivo excel y no en formato html

Comment: Es correcto. @JoseLuisSantiagoPacheco

Comment: Gracias, Lo intentare

Answer (score 2):

Tienes un *error de ortografía* en el código, después del `while` estas asignando una variable, `tiosresponsables`, y en `mensaje1` estás llamando otra diferente, `tiosresonsables` (faltó la P). Además de eso, se podria estructurar mejor el código, como eliminar los tags HTML en las asignaciones después del while porque no son necesarios y también eliminar los `echo` que están dentro de `mensaje1` ya que es una variable PHP, por tanto no los necesita. El código mejorado quedaría así:

```
<?php
    $conect = new mysqli("localhost", "onethost_horacio", "MPADT-2018", "onethost_MPA");
    $sql = "SELECT * from InformacionGeneral";
    $resultado=mysqli_query($conect,$sql);
    while($fila=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
        $idgeneral=$fila["Id_General"];
        $delegacion=$fila["Delegacion"];
        $parroquia=$fila["Parroquia"];
        $tios=$fila["Tios_Rensponsables"];
        $asesor=$fila["Asessor_Espiritual"];
        $fecha=$fila["Fecha"];
        $tiosresponsables=$fila["Tios_apoyo"];

        $mensaje1 = "<html>
        <head><title>Email con HTML</title></head>
        <body><h1>Email con HTML</h1>
        Esto es un email que se envía en el formato HTML
        <hr>
        Enviado por mi programa en PHP
        <hr>
        <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Id General</th><th>Delegacion</th><th>Parroquia</th><th>Tios</th><th>Asesor</th><th>Fecha</th><th>Tios Responsables</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>$idgeneral</td><td>$delegacion</td><td>$parroquia</td><td>$tios</td><td>$asesor</td><td>$fecha</td><td>$tiosresponsables</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </body>
        </html>";

    ////////////////////////////
    $asunto = "Datos de usuario";
    ///////////////////////////
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    //////////////////////////////////
    $headers .= "From: Jose Luis Santiago < jose@gmail.com >\r\n";
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    $para='santiago09617@gmail.com';
    /////////////////////////////////

    }
    $bool = mail($para,$asunto,$mensaje1,$headers);
    ?>
```

Comment: cierto, no me percate del error, deja lo pruebo y te dijo que paso va que va.

Comment: solo me manda un registro, actualmente tengo 4 registros solo me manda el 4. Te agradezco mucho tu ayuda, de todos modos ya quedo solucionado